# Constraintlayout and solver Constraintlayout can't detect in android sdk

Tags: android, android-layout

I was installed ***Constraintlayout and solver Constraintlayout***
[image: Constraintlayout and solver Constraintlayout], but that was not detected in my ***Android SDK*** [image: Android SDK].

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to restart Android Studio? Do you have the latest version? You already installed them using the checkbox? Are you sure the SDK you installed them to is the same AS is checking?

Comment: @MatPag - this same situation after I restart android studio. I am using android studio 3.0 and SDK tool version 26.1.1

Comment: Delete the folders related to ConstraintLayout in the SDK. Restart AS and invalidate the cache. Click on Show Package Details and select the last version of both the libraries, click apply, wait until download complete and then proceed with the installation. Restart AS